# Perl internals and Moose: constant-folding optimization

Tags: perl, moose, internals, constantfolding

I've been curious about constant-folding optimizations which Perl performs, but it occurred that when the code has Moose involved chances are that constant-folding won't be performed (please correct me if I am wrong).

I have Moose code which contains the method as below:

```
sub foo {
    my ($self) = shift;
    my $test_y = $self->pos->[1];
    #...
    if ($self->is_map_val($self->pos->[0]+8, $test_y+32) ||
        $self->is_map_val($self->pos->[0]+32-8, $test_y+32)) { 
    {
        heavy_stuff();
    }
    #...
}
```

and when I run `perl -MO=Deparse ./program.pl` I get almost identical code line:

```
if ($self->is_map_val($self->pos->[0] + 8, $test_y + 32) or    
    $self->is_map_val($self->pos->[0] + 32 - 8, $test_y + 32)) 
{
    heavy_stuff();
}
```

I wonder why Perl didn't optimize `32-8` as `24`? Are there any real reasons Perl didn't do that (maybe Moose subsystem makes the life harder?).

If it helps, I run Perl (v.5.14.2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Moose. In

```
$x + 32 - 8
```

the evaluation order is equivalent to

```
($x + 32) - 8
```

(i.e. `+` and `-` have same precedence level and are left-associative). As a tree:

```
    (-)
    / \
  (+)  8
  / \
$x   32
```

No part of that syntax tree has only constant nodes: `$x + 32` isn't constant, and `PREVIOUS_PART - 8` isn't constant either. Therefore, the constant folding (which only operates at this tree level, and can't reorder parts of the tree) doesn't see any chances for optimizations.

You do get the optimization of you reorder to `32 - 8 + $x`.

The [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Compile-pass-1a%3a-constant-folding) document constant folding, and specifically state that it operates by substituting parts of the tree.

Comment: thank you, it helps a lot. But in my case I didn't overload the addition operator.

Comment: @varnie I forgot that Perl doesn't mind much about overloading for constant folding. It is just an implementation detail of the way the constant folding is implemented. It just doesn't see that `32 - 8` is constant