# create a salary/bonus calculator

Tags: java

I have to create a salary/bonus calculator.

Depending on what salary is enter the bonus will be higher or lower/
eg. under 20000 will be 7% and over that will be 5.5%.

At the end of it I've to display the total amount of bonuses and the total amount of salaries with the bonus.
I'm having trouble with the totals when the program is done.

Here is my code.

```
class Salaries
{

    public static void main(String agrs[])
    {

        int salary; // this takes in each salary
        double salaryTotal = 0; // this adds the bonus to to salary
        double bonus = 0; // this hold the bonus amount.
        double sumSalary=0;
        double sumBonus=0;
        String exit = "y";// This is the string to be entered to exit the loop.

        // below I'm using a do/while loop to keep it going till a key that isn't "y is entered"
        do
        {

        // the try/catch makes sure that only a number is entered.
        try{
            // below prompts the user to enter the salary amount
        System.out.println("Enter an Employes wages.");
        // below takes in the salary
        salary = EasyIn.getInt();

        // if else ensure that the salary is not below 0  
        // and to determine if the amount of bonus to be added.
        if (salary <=-1)
        {
        System.out.println("The salary can not be less than 0");
        }

        else if  (salary >0 && salary <=20000)
            {
            bonus = salary*7/100; // This takes the entered salary and calculates the bonus.
            salaryTotal = salary + bonus;
            System.out.println("The bonus paid is " + bonus);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("The total salary + bonus is " + salaryTotal);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("Enter y to enter another Employes wages. ");

            System.out.println("Press any other letter to exit.");
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println();
            exit = EasyIn.getString();

            }
        else if (salary >20000 && salary <=30000)
            {
            bonus = salary*5.5/100; // This takes the entered salary and calculates the bonus.
            salaryTotal = salary + bonus;
            System.out.println("The bonus paid is " + bonus);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("The total salary + bonus is " + salaryTotal);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("Enter y to enter another Employes wages. ");

            System.out.println("Press any other letter to exit.");
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println();
            exit = EasyIn.getString();


            }

        else if (salary >30000 && salary <=40000)
            {

            bonus = salary*4/100;
            salaryTotal = salary + bonus; // This takes the entered salary and calculates the bonus.
            System.out.println("The bonus paid is " + bonus);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("The total salary + bonus is " + salaryTotal);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("Enter y to enter another Employes wages. ");

            System.out.println("Press any other letter to exit.");
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println();
            exit = EasyIn.getString();


            }

        else if (salary >40000)
            {
            bonus = salary*3.5/100;
            salaryTotal = salary + bonus; // This takes the entered salary and calculates the bonus.
            System.out.println("The bonus paid is " + bonus);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("The total salary + bonus is " + salaryTotal);
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println("Enter y to enter another Employes wages. ");

            System.out.println("Press any other letter to exit.");
            System.out.println("********************");
            System.out.println();
            exit = EasyIn.getString();



            }




        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!! Please enter a number.");
        }


        }


        while(exit.equals("y"));


        System.out.println("The total amout of bonus is " + sumBonus );
        System.out.println("The total of all the salaries is " + sumSalary);



    }




}
```

Comment: *Too much code repeat*. The only thing that changes the value used for calculation - so capture that in a variable and use it. The text and actual calculation should only appear *once*. Also, every use of `int/int` is wrong (and will lead to *integer division* and lose important precision), change it to `float/int` (so that it uses fp division), e.g. `7/100` -> `7.0/100`. The expression `5.5/100` is already correct in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

Make this a double. Division between int and double can lead to getting an integer back.

```
int salary; // this takes in each salary
```

For more information: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-int-div.html

Also it's a bit more efficient to do your bonus calculation as such:

```
bonus = salary * 0.055;
```

I'm also not seeing where you move the value from bonus to sumBonus for this line:

```
System.out.println("The total amout of bonus is " + sumBonus );
```

Perhaps change sumBonus to just bonus, don't forget to delete the declaration.

Comment: It's no more "efficient" to write `* 0.055` than it is to write `* (5.5/100)`. The compiler will fold such constant expressions. (And even if it did not, the difference in execution time is entirely *inconsequential* in such a case.)

Comment: Excuse me, elegant is what I was getting at. The bytecode would be the same, with your example, not his. He wrote it without the parentheses, meaning that the value is no longer a constant as the multiplication is applied first against the local variable. This alone results in an extra 4 bytes of bytecode. As for this example it is inconsequential, though optimization is still a good habit to develop early. I tested this theory by hand using jclasslib BC viewer. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579505/perl-internals-and-moose-constant-folding-optimization)